# iOS setting.bundle issue with iOS 5.0

Tags: ios

Did anything change with settings.bundle and NSUserDefeauts in iOS 5.0 compare to iOS 4.3?

My problem is as follow.
If I have a toogleswitch and a defaultvalue as no.
And I launch the setting app and scrolls down to my app and tap on it. The NSUserDetaults is being set to the default value as NO. This is happening in iOS 5.0. I do not think this was happening on iOS 4.3.

Comment: Are you setting the default in your code or in the Interface Builder? (meant to comment not post).

Comment: I am setting it in the root.plist. I guess my questions is this the expected behavior of the setting app in both iOS 5.0 and 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Plists never quite go over the pipe completely.  Clean, clean the build folder, and if all else fails, go to the organizer and delete your project's derived data. Do everything you can to make Xcode have to work to rebuild the file hierarchy in your sandbox, and it will copy the plist over.  I've found that it also helps if you tap on a different tab in Settings.app and then close it before you launch a new build, because there might be some kind of caching going on.